# Validate soft foreign key Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Have a `model` in `django` that has a `json` field with list of `IDs`
to a different `model`.
How can we validate the inputs to that field are valid `foreign key`.

Not using `many to many field` or a joining `model` separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a strange way of doing things but your best option would be to get a list of your valid IDs with `MyModel.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)` and compare your JSON data with the resulting list

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is compere jsonlist lenght with this count: `MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=jsonlist).count()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. However question was to validate each of the ids received in the json that each of that id is of a valid object.